# How do I pull information from a field in the admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am currently working with Django 1.8 and Python 3. I'm using Python-social-auth to let people sign in via steam id and I'm using the **`SOCIAL_AUTH_STEAM_EXTRA_DATA = ['player']`**
setting. In the admin panel you get an field that says Extra Data. And it stores info like this

**`{"player": {"profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198039465340/", "personaname": "Khailz | Daisuki <3", "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9c/9cce70b919de60669303d057446fbf563221133a_medium.jpg", "steamid": "76561198039465340", "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/9c/9cce70b919de60669303d057446fbf563221133a_full.jpg"}}`**

What I want to do is pull the avatarfull data and put it in my template when a user is logged in.

I have currently tried things like `<p>{{ user.get_user_details.avatarfull }}</p>` in my login.html and any other combination trying to pull this specific field. I'm not sure how to go about this, how do I pick this field out if it is backend and not in the models.py? I know I'm going about this wrong could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think the correct path is:

```
user.social_auth.get(
    provider='steam'
).extra_data.player.avatarfull
```

Which isn't very convenient, so you might want to add a property to your User object:

#### models:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    # regular stuff

    @property
    def get_avatar_url(self):
        try:
            return self.social_auth.get(
                provider='steam'
            ).extra_data.player.avatarfull
        except (UserSocialAuth.DoesNotExist, AttributeError):
            return 'http://placehold.it/64x64'
```

#### templates:

```
<img src="{{ user.get_avatar_url }}" />
```

If you haven't declared a custom user object, you could just as easily create a templatetag or stand alone helper function to retrieve the avatar from an user.

#### templatetag:

```
@register.filter
def get_avatar_url(user):
    try:
        return user.social_auth.get(
            provider='steam'
        ).extra_data.player.avatarfull
    except (UserSocialAuth.DoesNotExist, AttributeError):
        return 'http://placehold.it/64x64'
```

#### templates:

```
<img src="{{ user|get_avatar_url }}" />
```

Comment: I tried your method out but no luck unless I'm just doing it wrong, but I feel like I'm slowly getting it. Which would you say is the better method models or the template tag?

Comment: Finally got it with no models or template tags, I used `{{ user.social_auth.get.extra_data.player.avatarfull }}` which got the users avatar from the extra data. The path you mentioned is for multiple social auths I think

Comment: actually your path works because get simply pulls a single result from the queryset, it will fail if the resulting queryset is empty or contains multiple items. I would avoid using get without a try/except wrapper, see the updated answer for a template tag solution.